# Ionic 3 URL not updating

Tags: angular, ionic3

In my `app.component.ts` I set `rootPage` to `LoginComponent` like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Deeplinks} from '@ionic-native/deeplinks';


@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
rootPage:any = 'login';

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
             SplashScreen, private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

   });
  }
}
```

Then in my `LoginComponent` I use

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot('friend-list');
```

`friend-list` is component which is decorated by

```
@IonicPage({
 name: 'friend-list',
 segment: 'friend-list'
})
```

Problem is that I always in my browser I have static localhost like
`localhost:8100/#/login`, whenever I am in my app, but if I enter `localhost:8100/#/friend-list` app goes properly to the component. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Any idea for this case?

Comment: " app goes properly to the component" <- what does this mean? Are you saying that the app should not be allowed to navigate to friend-list and should go straight to the login ?

Comment: Main problem is that, if I goes from Login to Friend-list my url i browser stay the same -> `localhost:8100/#/login`, I would like there `localhost:8100/#/friend-list` url

Comment: Ok .. so i am not sure what the problem might be but i dont think you should be referencing in the `setRoot` by the segment name but rather the exported class name. `this.navCtrl.setRoot('FriendList');` .. I think

Comment: Yeah, that's works, thank you very much !!!

Comment: this is a duplicated post of [this one where i posted a solution working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164952/cannot-create-routes-on-ionic-3/46201576#46201576). Hope it'll help.

Comment: This is a duplicated post of [this one where i posted a solution working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164952/cannot-create-routes-on-ionic-3/46201576#46201576). Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue drove me nuts and I finally solved it this way.

In "app.module.ts" i import "DeepLinker" and "DeepLinkConfig" and add a "link" array into the "imports" array to specify the name of all my pages. Like this:

```
import { DeepLinker, DeepLinkConfig } from 'ionic-angular';

imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  mode: 'md',
  animate: 'ios-transition'
  }, {
    links: [      
      { component: HomePage, name: 'page-home', segment: 'page-home' }
    ]
  })
]
```

Next, on the page that has the navigation button, I set a click event to call the following function:

```
goToURL() {
  //'page-home' has to be the value you provided for "name" in the "link" array above
  this.events.publish('page:navigated', 'page-home');
}
```

Finally in my "app.component.ts" I import Events and NavController if it's not already in there and I subscribe to the event that was just published from the function above:

```
import { Events, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

events.subscribe('page:navigated', (page) => {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);
});
```